# Change button value based on image visibility

Tags: jquery

I have multiple images, each of which has its own button. I'm trying to get the value of the button that was clicked to change to "Hide" When the image (corresponding) is visible but show "Show" when the image (corresponding) is hidden. Only one of the buttons works as intended. Any Ideas on how I can achieve this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hideAndShow").click(function() {
    var clickValue = $('.hideAndShow').attr('value');
    $(".imager img").eq($(this).index()).toggle();
    if (clickValue == 'Hide') {
      $('.hideAndShow').eq($("img:hidden").index()).attr('value', 'Show');
    } else if (clickValue == 'Show') {
      $('.hideAndShow').eq($("img:visible").index()).attr('value', 'Hide');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.imager {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 50px 25px 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.imager img {
  height: 100%;
  auto: auto;
  background: green;
  padding: 0 50px 25px 50px;
}
.hideAndShow {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imager">
  <img src="xid-57735235_1.jpg" width="620" height="453" alt="" />
  <input type="button" class="hideAndShow" value="Hide">
</div>

<div class="imager">
  <img src="xid-57735236_1.jpg" width="620" height="410" alt="" />
  <input type="button" class="hideAndShow" value="Hide">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Praveen

Comment: I also answered the right way to do it @sleek. Kindly check and if looks good, please accept! `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you complicating things? Using `this` is the right way. Just use the short function this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hideAndShow").click(function() {
    if ($(this).prev("img").is(":visible")) {
      $(this).prev("img").hide();
      $(this).val("Show");
    } else {
      $(this).prev("img").show();
      $(this).val("Hide");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.imager {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 50px 25px 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.imager img {
  height: 100%;
  auto: auto;
  background: green;
  padding: 0 50px 25px 50px;
}
.hideAndShow {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imager">
  <img src="xid-57735235_1.jpg" width="620" height="453" alt="" />
  <input type="button" class="hideAndShow" value="Hide">
</div>

<div class="imager">
  <img src="xid-57735236_1.jpg" width="620" height="410" alt="" />
  <input type="button" class="hideAndShow" value="Hide">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @SleekGeek Works. `:)`